# please help! i can sort items to hidden overflow!

Tags: jquery, sorting, overflow, jquery-ui-sortable, hidden

[This is my site](http://bazzoo.bz-bz.com/site.html). On the left I have a playlist, inside a container with hidden overflow (the playlist is a sortable). The playlist grows as you drag more songs to it from the search list.

The problem is that when you drag many songs to the playlist, and the playlist is larger than the container, it makes a situation where I can sort the playlist by dragging items to the hidden area. In other words, I can drag a song from the playlist to an area under the container (where the invisible part of the playlist is) and the song will still be inserted to the list.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this project is becoming too big for HTML/jQuery, consider making it in flash.

Comment: What do you want us to help you achieve with this question?

Comment: this is not supposed to happen. i should only be able to sort inside the sorted list. i don't know how to fix it. (and no, i can't make it flash)

Answer (score 1):

Good question. But yes, that would be the expected behavior. I can only think of a 'hacky' solution to the problem, which would be to place an invisible `div` element with a very high z-index over the part where you don't want dropping to take place. This should provide a pragmatic solution to your problem, but it isn't pretty.

In fact, a reasonably good solution would be to add that invisible element dynamically as soon as the drag action starts, so as to stop the user from dropping there. When the drag stops, you can remove it again.

**Update**
Ok, so learning that the first try doesn't work, I went to have a look at the [jQuery docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-containment). They specify a `containment` option, which is an element in which the sorting should be contained. So I'd say you can do the invisible element thing again, but this time place it exactly on top of the area you want to be able to sort in. Then, specify this element in the `containment` option. If that doesn't work, I'm out of advice ;)

Comment: wow.. i didn't think of that.. you gave me hope XD.
i'll try it and will let you know soon!
Thank you very much!

Comment: it didn't work.. :(  i did what you said and it didn't work. i even tried to make that new div a sortable, and place it on the playList sortable. that didn't work too. i added this image to show you.http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/3166/97235980.png

Comment: (its the html viewer in explorer)

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i already tried that. it restricts the movement of the items to only the inside of the container, so it makes it ugly and less friendly to the user. so i don't want to do this, though it does solve it. Thanks a lot anyway. I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Hmm yes, in the end you'll have to choose I guess. Honestly, I don't see why it's such a big problem that the user is able to do that. The most usable experience, if you ask me, would be to start scrolling down or up if the user leaves that box, but not to let the dragged element leave the list.